# Classic ASP - looping through folder with large amount of images

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, filesystemobject

I am maintaining a site that uses a HTML editor with an image upload feature. When you click upload it opens a popup that lists a path to every image in the folder. There are currently more than 7000 images in the folder.

The code is quite messy. It uses the Scripting.FileSystemObject to get an array of the files and then loops using a for each statement.A response.write is used to display each file's info and for some reason an issue is occurring if there's more than 4015 images in the folder. No error is occurring as such but it seems the function writing out the files just fails silently and the page stops rendering.

I am confused why it works when there's less than 4015 files. Could it be a memory issue ? I was expecting to receive an error of some sort.

Thanks for any info.

Below is the Response.Write being used for each file

```
            Response.Write "<tr style='background:" & sColorResult & "'>" & VbCrLf & _
            "<td><img src='images/"&sIcon&"'></td>" & VbCrLf & _
            "<td valign=top width=100% ><u id=""idFile"&nIndex&""" style='cursor:pointer;' onclick=""selectFile(" & nIndex & ")"">" & oFile.name & "</u>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img style='cursor:pointer;' onclick=""downloadFile(" & nIndex & ")"" src='download.gif'></td>" & VbCrLf & _

            "<td valign=top align=right nowrap>" & FormatNumber(oFile.size/1000,1) & " kb&nbsp;</td>" & VbCrLf & _          
            "<td valign=top nowrap onclick=""deleteFile(" & nIndex & ")""><u style='font-size:10px;cursor:pointer;color:crimson' " & sFolderAdmin & ">" & VbCrLf

        if not bWriteFolderAdmin then
            Response.Write "<script>document.write(getTxt('del'))</script>" & VbCrLf
        end if

        Response.Write "</u></td></tr>" & VbCrLf
```

Comment: If you write less, can you display more than 4015 files? For example, try writing just the file names (`"<tr><td>" & oFile.Name & "</td></tr>"`).

Comment: No error message. @Bond I was trying this yesterday and it was working with less text in the response.write string. What could be the reason for this ? Memory ? Thanks

Comment: I don't think it would be memory related, since you're writing each as you go (not in a big chunk). Could be that your Response size is limited, however.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Could i place it in a variable instead and then Response.Write the variable ? (I cannot test this until later)

Comment: Some of the image filenames are very long. I guess these could add to the response size ?

Comment: Do you have buffering enabled? Also, I'm assuming the page just stops rendering? It's not still showing your page footer, right?

Comment: sorry, i'm not sure what you mean by enabling buffering. Would this be set at the top of the page ? Yes, it just stops rendering the page.

Comment: Buffering means that ASP will not write anything to the page until it's fully rendered OR you call `Response.Flush()`. I believe it's enabled by default on IIS 6. Try inserting this *as the very first line* in your page: `<% Response.Buffer = False %>`.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. Add as an answer and ill accept

Comment: I don't have time to check yet. Ill reply this evening when i can test.

Comment: @Bond see above. (you might have missed it as OP is not using `@`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the issue here was the response buffer filling up. Either of these solutions should work:

1. Disable buffering by adding `Response.Buffer = False` as the first line of code.
2. Leave buffering enabled but call `Response.Flush()` at certain intervals to flush the buffer.